# unable to understand Read[T]JsPath example in documentation

Tags: json, playframework

I am unable to understand example code of JsPath and Read in the documentation

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ScalaJsonCombinators

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
```

Question 1 - We create a custom reader. Reads should be able to read a structure of data consisting of String, Float and a List. But in the example below, we pass it a Json! How is the Json getting converted to (String, Fload and List)?

Question 2 - we use JsPath \ "key1" but where have we passed the JSON?

```
val customReads: Reads[(String, Float, List[String])] = 
  (JsPath \ "key1").read[String](email keepAnd minLength(5)) and 
  (JsPath \ "key2").read[Float](min(45)) and
  (JsPath \ "key3").read[List[String]] 
  tupled

import play.api.libs.json.Json

val js = Json.obj(
  "key1" -> "alpha", 
  "key2" -> 123.345F, 
  "key3" -> Json.arr("alpha", "beta")
)

res5: JsSuccess(("alpha", 123.345F, List("alpha", "beta")))

scala> customReads.reads(js) 
customReads.reads(js).fold(
      invalid = { errors => ... },
      valid = { res => 
        val (s, f, l): (String, Float, List[String]) = res
        ...
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**

> We create a custom reader.

Yes

> Reads should be able to read a structure of data consisting of String, Float and a List.

No

```
val customReads: Reads[(String, Float, List[String])]= ...
```

Means that `customReads` is the variable of type `Reads`, and that `Reads.reads` must **return** tuple of types `(String, Float, List[String])`

> But in the example below, we pass it a JSON! How is the JSON getting converted to (String, Float and List)?

`Reads.reads` is a function that takes JSON as a parameter and returns some value, extracted from the JSON by defined rules. In our case, the rules are:

```
(JsPath \ "key1").read[String](email keepAnd minLength(5))
```

**and**

```
(JsPath \ "key2").read[Float](min(45))
```

**and**

```
(JsPath \ "key3").read[List[String]]
```

all these values must be

```
tupled
```

so our `Reads.reads` function returns `(String, Float, List[String])` tuple.

**Question 2**

> we use JsPath \ "key1" but where have we passed the JSON?

`JsPath \ "key1"` is not the actual code to process the JSON, it's a rule to process a JSON. i.e it is like XPath expression `/key1`

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. A follow up question - where is 'reads' overwritten? The scala documentation declares 'reads' as`abstract def
reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[A]`. I am guessing is has to be related to the apply method `def apply[A](f: JsValue => JsResult[A]): Reads[A] = new Reads[A] { def reads(json: JsValue) = f(json)
  }` but I am unable to join the dots.

Comment: The code inside is complex, it's like creating functions from functions and changing that functions.  So `(JsPath \ "key1").read[String]` create some function and then `and` create another function that is combined with the next `(JsPath \ "key2").read[String]` and so on, and the `tupled` create the `Read` object with the `reads` function that is defined according to previous combinations